# How to apply LGBM model predict over a Pyspark Dataframe if the model expect categorical columns

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a LGBM model packed in a pickle file. This model expects 15 features, 3 of them categoric in character format (2 of them have numbers values but they aren't ordinal). For example:

Categorical Features:
| RESIDENCE_GROUP | DISTRITO | SR_BRANDMODEL |
| --------------- | -------- | ------------- |
| 20              | Rimac    | 1             |
| 15              | Cayma    | 3             |

LGBM Model:

```
LGBMRegressor(alpha=0.47, bagging_fraction=0.9993975742322292, bagging_freq=12,
              boosting='gbdt',
              categorical_features=['SR_BRANDMODEL', 'DISTRITO',
                                    'RESIDENCE_GROUP'],
              feature_fraction=0.745910363407423,
              learning_rate=0.15141957598725495, metric='mape',
              min_data_in_leaf=1280, num_iterations=1020, num_leaves=13,
              num_threads=8, objective='quantile', random_state=10, silent=True,
              verbosity=-1)
```

In another hand, I have a pyspark dataframe that has all of this 15 features ready (since pyspark dataframe can't handle categorical columns those 3 features are string type).

I have tried to use VectorAssembler to get a dense vector column but it doesn't accept string types. I have also tried StringIndexer to get a numeric value of those 3 features but, since the model expects another values, i think it won't work.

What can I do to predict over this Pyspark Dataframe?